# How can I get the top x products of each brand in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Spreadsheet that retrieves product data containing the SKU, Name of the product, the revenue in the past x days. Using a Regexmatch function I retrieve the brands from the products that will be in sale the coming weeks.

Now I want to retrieve the top 5 products of each brand (based on highest revenue) and if I use the Query function I am not able to get the limit per brand sorted. How can I do this? Hereby an example of the dataset: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ysERREFus9sKuF99roj2fLQYvqNBZx-L9iNknExCfY/edit#gid=0

Comment: Please show a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

`=SORT(filter({A2:C,IF(ISBLANK(D2:D),"NO_BRAND",D2:D)},MAP(IF(ISBLANK(D2:D),"NO_BRAND",D2:D),C2:C,LAMBDA(dx,cx,if(dx="",,RANK(cx,FILTER(C2:C,IF(ISBLANK(D2:D),"NO_BRAND",D2:D)=dx),0))))<6),4,0,3,0)`

-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce()` to iterate brands, and `order by C desc limit 5` to get the top five products per brand, like this:

```
=reduce( 
  Dataset!A1:D1, unique(Dataset!D2:D), 
  lambda( 
    result, brand, 
    { 
      result; 
      query( 
        Dataset!A2:D, 
        "where D = '" & brand & "' 
         and A is not null 
         order by C desc 
         limit 5", 
        0 
      ) 
    } 
  ) 
)
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ysERREFus9sKuF99roj2fLQYvqNBZx-L9iNknExCfY/edit#gid=470257007).